# Basis of Complex vector space, complex conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am not sure whether if this statement is correct,

For each basis $\beta =\left \{ \vec x_{1} , \vec x_{2},..., \vec x_{n}  \right \}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$, the set $\alpha=\left \{ \overline{\vec x_{1}} , \overline{\vec x_{2}},...,  \overline{\vec x_{n}}  \right \}$  is a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Here is my thought,
I think the statement is false, the complex conjugate of a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is different from itself. If all the entries of a vector are real, then the complex conjugate is just itself, it does not change, so $\left \{ \vec x_{1} , \vec x_{2},..., \vec x_{n}  \right \}=\left \{ \overline{\vec x_{1}} , \overline{\vec x_{2}},...,  \overline{\vec x_{n}}  \right \}$ but this only works for the real vectors.

I am really not sure if $\left \{ \overline{\vec x_{1}} , \overline{\vec x_{2}},...,  \overline{\vec x_{n}}  \right \}$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ if $\left \{ \vec x_{1} , \vec x_{2},..., \vec x_{n}  \right \}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$, and is this true for each basis?
And how do you prove it if it is true or disprove it?
Maybe somehow related to linear independence?

I have tried a few example, and it seems that this statement is true?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The statement is true. I will change the notation slightly by using capital letrres for vectors. Suppose $\{X_1,X_2,..,X_n\}$ is a basis. If $\sum c_k\overline {X_k}=0%$ then we can take conjugate on both sides to get $\sum \overline {c_k} X_k=0$.  This implies $\overline {c_k} =0$ for each $k$ and hence $c_k=0$ for eachy $k$. Hence $\{ \overline  {X_1}, \overline  {X_2},..,\overline  {X_n}\}$ is linearly independent Since the sapce $\mathbb  C^{n}$ is $n$ dimensional it is a basis.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I still have some doubts, so we have $\overline c_k=0$ then, why the set is linear independent? how does it implies that it is linear independence?

Comment: oh!! I got it, nevermind